# how to extract only year from date in solr?

Tags: solr

how to extract only year from date in solr?
I'm getting year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds when querying the date from solr. How can I get only YEAR from the solr query?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to query Solr over the range of a given year, or are you asking how to extract the year from a date field returned in the results?

Answer (score 3):

We do not have any built in functions in solr for that. But, you can achieve the objective with some mathematical calculations in solr.

```
year = floor(sum(div(ms(created_at), mul(1000, 60, 60, 24, 365)), 1970))
```

**For Calculating Hours in this**

Let us say you have a date - 2018-05-17 10:00:00 (d1), to extract **hours** we can do the following.

1. Get the dates timestamp. (d1)
2. Get that days timestamp at starting of the day, i.e 2018-05-17 00:00:00. (d2)
3. Now subtract both of these, i.e. (d1 - d2). This will give number of hours passed in that day.
4. Now divide this by 1000 * 60 * 60 to get the current hour. You can round off to get the accurate result.

Example -

```
1. start_time_of_created_at = mul(floor(div(ms(created_at), mul(1000, 60, 60, 24))), mul(1000, 60, 60, 24))
2. start_time_of_hours_of_created_at = mul(floor(div(ms(latest_successful_visit_at), mul(1000, 60, 60))), mul(1000, 60, 60))
3. hours = rint(div(sub($start_time_of_hours_of_created_at, $start_time_of_created_at), mul(1000, 60, 60)))
```

Although, this won't work for dates and months as their are different number of days in each month. Also, we haven't incorporated leap years in this, hence this is not a very good solution for year as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot do it. Solr can only deal with ranges of dates, just like it only deals with ranges of numbers or ranges of strings. Asking Solr to only query a date field based on the first day of the month is like asking it to query on a numeric field and only give you odd numbers, or querying a string but only those starting with vowels.

What you'll need to do is break up the date into month and day components and then query on those. If your base field is sale_date, you'll also need sale_month and sale_day. Then you can query on month:3 to get everything that happened in any March, or day:1 and get everything for the first day of any month or month:3 AND day:1 to get everything that happened on any March 1st.

You can do the similar for Years, break the date, make a new field for years and query on top of it.